# Cant find a way to iterate over XMP profile arrays

Tags: c#, metadata-extractor

Using [MetaData-Extractor-Dotnet](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) I am having difficulty getting at all the information that Adobe products save into the XMP profile.

I need to convert this metadata into a standard JSON format for use in my app where items will always be where they are expected across different versions of XMP saved by different versions of Adobe products. For example, I need to know that imageCreator will always be an array of objects of name and type; or that PersonInImage will always be just an array of strings.

Therefore just iterating all the properties and converting to a plain flat json object isn't much use as the names (which include indexes) will be pretty random and unusable by the eventually consumer of the json.

I am using the code from the Wiki:

```
foreach (var xmpDirectory in directories.OfType<XmpDirectory>())
{
    foreach (var property in xmpDirectory.XmpMeta.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{property.Path}: {property.Value}");
    }
}
```

However its not returning some of the elements which are 'arrays' of 'properties' of information (I think XMP call these Composite Properties).

Here is an example of an array of information in the XMP RDF profile:

```
<plus:ImageCreator>
   <rdf:Seq>
      <rdf:li plus:ImageCreatorName="Guy NoName" plus:ImageCreatorID="Producer" />
      <rdf:li plus:ImageCreatorName="John SillyMan" plus:ImageCreatorID="Cameraman" />
   </rdf:Seq>
</plus:ImageCreator>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
foreach (var xmpDirectory in directories.OfType<XmpDirectory>())
{
    foreach (var property in xmpDirectory.XmpMeta.Properties)
    {
        if( property.Options.IsArray )
        {
            int count = xmpDirectory.XmpMeta.CountArrayItems( property.Namespace, property.Path );
            for( var p = 0; p < count; p++ )
            {
                var item = xmpDirectory.XmpMeta.GetArrayItem( property.Namespace, property.Path, p + 1 );
                if( item.Options.IsCompositeProperty )
                {
                    // THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( $"Item {p}: {item.Value}" );
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{property.Path}: {property.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone let me know if its possible?

Comment: Never mind, I have done it a different way by just analysing the flattened .Path property and using the index and path values to determine if i should create a list of strings or a list of objects